# How should "to whom the word of God came" in John 10:35 be understood?

Tags: john

John 10:35 Literal Standard Version

> If He called them gods to whom the word of God came (and the Writing
> is not able to be broken),

To whom did the word of God come?

Answer (score 2):

Jesus is referring to the religious leaders of the Jews.

He had just been accused of blasphemy (John 10:33) and wants the people to understand that He is defending rather than attacking the law.  The leaders have received *the word of God* and have been set apart and given authority, and Jesus affirms rather than deny this, despite their error.  Theophylact explains:

> When Christ said, *I and the Father are one,* the Jews picked up
> stones to stone Him, but now He refutes their charge by quoting from
> the Psalms [82:6/81:6 LXX]. He shows that the word *gods* is used in the Scriptures to
> refer to judges, who have been appointed to represent God's judgment
> on earth. The title of *gods* is given to those who have received the
> *word of God* and have been set apart for a special purpose. It does not
> imply that they are equal to God in power or authority. Rather, it
> signifies their authority to judge on God's behalf and to speak His
> word to the people.
>
> But why does He call them *gods*? Because they have received the word of
> God and have been appointed to represent the one true God. Those who
> hear them hear God, for they are speaking His words. And so, because
> they are *called gods*, *and the Scripture cannot be broken*, we should
> honor the Scriptures and obey their every word (*PG* 123:654-657).

Other Church Fathers who concur with this explanation - that those to whom the word of God came were the religious leaders of the Jews - include Gregory of Nyssa,<sup>1</sup> Augustine,<sup>2</sup> and Jerome.<sup>3</sup>  Ambrose of Milan<sup>4</sup> also concurs, but believed that Jesus was also referring to the prophets, as does Cyril of Alexandria.<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>1.</sup> <sup>*On the Soul and Resurrection*</sup>
<sup>2.</sup> <sup>*Tractate 48* on John</sup>
<sup>3.</sup> <sup>*Commentary on Matthew*, Book III</sup>
<sup>4.</sup> <sup>*Commentary on Luke*, Book VII</sup>
<sup>5.</sup> <sup>*Commentary on John*, Book VII</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The verse Jesus is referencing is found in the Psalms.

> I have said, Ye are gods; and all of you are children of the most
> High. (Psalm 82:6, KJV)

The verse immediately follows a statement made about the wicked, and shows a contrast between these to whom God is speaking and the wicked.

> <sup>4</sup>. . . rid them out of the hand of the wicked.
> <sup>5</sup>They know not, neither will they understand; they walk on
> in darkness: all the foundations of the earth are out of course.
> (Psalm 82:4-5, KJV)

So the text is saying that the wicked "know not, neither will they understand."  These, apparently, are *not* the ones whom God is calling "gods."  This is why Jesus specifies the ones who know--because they have received God's word--as being the ones called "gods."

### Conclusion

The word of God came to *God's people*, whom He called "gods": by implication, the special focus would be the Israelites.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the Israelites, in the context, their ancestors, referred to as third person instead of *our ancestors*.

> [Rom 9:3-5 NASB] For I could wish that I myself were accursed, [separated] from Christ for the sake of my brethren, my kinsmen according to the flesh, who are Israelites, to whom belongs the adoption as sons, and the glory and the covenants and the giving of the Law and the [temple] service and the promises, whose are the fathers, and from whom is the Christ according to the flesh, who is over all, God blessed forever. Amen.
>
> Rom 3:2 Great in every respect. First of all, that they were entrusted with the oracles of God.

TSK chain [ref](https://www.stepbible.org/?q=version=ESV%7Cversion=NETfull%7Cversion=NIV%7Cversion=THGNT%7Creference=Neh.9.13-Neh.9.14%20Ps.147.19%20Ezek.20.11-Ezek.20.12%20John.1.17%20Rom.3.2&options=GVNUVH&display=INTERLEAVED): Rom 3:2; Neh 9:13; Neh 9:14; Ps 147:19; Ezek 20:11; Ezek 20:12; John 1:17

Comment: And the LORD said to Moses, “See, I have made you like God to Pharaoh, and your brother Aaron shall be your prophet.
(Exodus 7:1, ESV)

Answer (score 1):

Jesus was quoting from the written Law, a point that would be well known to his audience in Solomon's Porch in the Temple. The little bit he quoted would be a point they would believe applied to those of their forebears who were the appointed leaders of the nation of Israel. Not the Romans, of course, the Jewish leaders. In the time of Jesus, those were predominantly the religious leaders, based in the Temple.

Those Jewish religious leaders were viewed as God's representatives. They held a sacred position, thus the Hebrew scriptures referred to them as "gods" (with a small 'g'). This title is used several times in the Hebrew scriptures. Moses' brother, Aaron, was Moses' representative spokesman, causing Pharaoh to view Moses as God, and even Aaron to view Moses as in place of God (Exodus 4:15-16 & 7:1). Then it is used in the Psalms of those Israelites who were responsible for passing on God's word and judgments to his people. Judges, kings, and religious leaders - all were representatives of the Almighty. As such, they were 'mighty ones' though never, of course, almighty. Hence the small 'g' in the 82nd Psalm:

> "God standeth in the congregation of the mighty; he judgeth among the
> gods."
>
> "I have said, Ye are gods; and all of you are children of the most
> High. But ye shall die like men, and fall like one of the princes."
> Psalm 82 vss 1 & 6 J.K.V.

This provides ***the answer as to who Jesus meant when he referred to those ones, "to whom the word of God came"***. That particular word came both in Exodus and in the Psalms, to **people who were God's representatives on earth, amongst his chosen people of Israel**. The ones to whom Jesus spoke (reminding them of what God had said to their selective forebears) would sting them, as it showed they could not accuse him of blasphemy for claiming to be the Son of God, sent by God into the world as God's representative.

Answer (score 0):

Moses is the one most clearly referenced:

> He shall speak for you to the people, and he shall be your mouth, and you shall be as God to him.
> (Exodus 4:16, ESV)

> And the LORD said to Moses, “See, I have made you like God to Pharaoh, and your brother Aaron shall be your prophet. (Exodus 7:1, ESV)

Some reference this passage in Psalms, but it is not clear to whom it refers:

```
        I said, “You are gods, 
  sons of the Most High, all of you; 
               nevertheless, like men you shall die, 
  and fall like any prince.” 
                       (Psalm 82:6–7, ESV)
```